# Unable to get constant variable in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5

I create file named `constants.php` in `project\config` folder

The content is

```
<?php

return [

  'foo' => 'bar',

];

?>
```

But I get empty response while I do `config('constants.foo')` or `Config::get('constants.foo')`

Where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try to burst the cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the autoloader and clear the config cache.

Run

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Then

```
php artisan config:clear
```